# Hover state of multilevel dropdown

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, hover

I am working on a sidebar navigation I was asked to work on.  The dropdown has two levels and the first level is functioning fine but the second level has an odd padding issue that I can't figure out.  I am by no means an expert so please go easy on me, I just cannot figure out why on the 2nd level(light blue area) the hover state does not fill the entire nav area there is padding on the top and bottom.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

[Here is my JSFiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/jricharc/39poj3g6/)

```
    <body>
<div id="subpageContentWrapper">
    <!--page container with white background and 16px top/bottom margins-->
    <div class="subpageContent_w-subnav">
        <div class="subnavColumn">  
            <div class="subnavContainer">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Employee Resources Home</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="">Employee Actions</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Update Personal Information &amp; Benefits (HR Connect)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Office Personnel File (OPF)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Verify Employment</a></li>
                            <li class="activeSub"><a href="">Hardship Transfers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Part Time IRS Employment</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Resignation / Separation</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Outside Employment</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Relocation</a></li>
                        </ul>                       
                    </li>
                    <li class="inactive"><a href="">Retirement</a>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="inactive"><a href="">Benefits</a>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="inactive"><a href="">Pay</a>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="inactive"><a href="">Timekeeping</a>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="inactive"><a href="">Travel</a>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="inactive"><a href="">Credit Card Services</a>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="inactive"><a href="">Accessibility</a>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="inactive"><a href="">Equity, Diversity &amp; Inclusion (EDI)</a>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Employee Rights &amp; Obligations</a></li>
                    <li class="inactive"><a href="">Employee Forms</a>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div><!-- close subnavContainer -->    

        </div><!--subnavColumn-->
</body>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/39poj3g6/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in the active section you have a `:hover` rule on the `<li>` which is larger than the `<a>`, but in the other section you have the `:hover` rule on the `<a>` which is smaller.

Add a `:hover` rule to the `<li>` and it will work. Try this:

```
.subnavContainer ul li:not(.active):hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```